# Am I have right answer about dual problem?

Tags: duality-theorems

I have some problems to make from primal problem to dual problem.

If I have the primal problem like down below.

Problem

$$ \text{Min} \qquad 3w_1 + 4w_2 + 5w_3 $$
$$  w_1 - w_2      \le ε_1 $$
$$             w_2 - w_3 \le ε_2 $$
$$                   w_3 \le ε_3 $$
$$                     1 \le 2ε_1 +3ε_2 + 4ε_3 $$
$$        w_1 + w_2 + w_3 = 1  $$

then I think its dual problem with dual variable x is

$$ \text{Max} \qquad ε_1x_1 + ε_2x_2 + ε_3x_3 + (2ε_1 +3ε_2 + 4ε_3)x_4 + x_5$$
$$ s.t.  x_1 + x_5 \le3 $$
$$       x_2       \le 4 $$
$$       x_3       \le 5 $$
$$  \text{where} \quad r_4 \quad \text{and} \quad r_5 \quad \text{are} \quad \text{unrestricted} \quad \text{in }
 \quad \text{sign}. $$

am I right?

Comment: It seems that $\epsilon_n$ are decision variables from the constraint $$ 1 \le 2\epsilon_1 ...$$ in the primal program.  In general, please use the [SOB table](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2711828/290189) to solve it.

Comment: https://vincenttam.gitlab.io/post/2019-04-26-my-dual-answer/